# Flask / Angular / Nginx Session issue

Tags: python, angularjs, cookies, nginx, flask

Cant figure out why the flask session is having issues when requests are sent to separate instances.

1. We log the user in via Flask-Login `login_user(user_data)`,
2. Session is created by Flask-Login, cookie is created
3. However if the user creates another request and the load balancer routes that request to another instance, the session is lost (essentially the cookie is reset/overwrote)

Here is my current nginx config

```
location / { 
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
    proxy_cookie_domain media.$host $host;
    proxy_pass_header  Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect false;
    try_files $uri @www;
}
```

The angularjs app is configured to send the cookie with each request:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Flask session settings:

```
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = timedelta(days=2)

@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
session.permanent = True
```

Comment: Do you use the same `SECRET_KEY` in all your Flask nodes?

Comment: Miguel, the secret key is the same across each instance.

Comment: Then you need to inspect the requests as they enter your Flask application. If the cookie is not there, then the problem is on the nginx side. If the cookie is there, then it may have something that makes Flask decide it is invalid.

Comment: you need better solution wrt [session tracking](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/category/sessions/), as you have multiple instances and they all have isolated namespaces instead of common one. you might need to look at some ticket / principal mechanism, especially if load balancing is dynamic.